# Member 0 does not have permission to get company with linkedin JS SDK

Tags: javascript, rest, sdk, linkedin-api

I have a small issue with getting number of followers from a company profile - which I am the admin of and I have set the "rw_company_admin" permission.

I am getting "Member 0 does not have permission to get company XXXXX".

If testing with the REST Console I get the number of followers and if I paste the URL with the access_token in a browser tab I get the number of followers, but with the JS SDK get the above mentioned error. I am using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key: XXXXX
        onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
        authorize: true
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function onLinkedInLoad() {                     

            IN.API.Raw("/companies/XXXXX:(num-followers)").result( function(result) {       
                $('#dashRightLinkedIn').html(addCommas(result.numFollowers));
            }).error( function(error) { 
                console.log(error);
            });

        }
</script>
```

What do I miss?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key: XXXXX
        onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
        authorize: true
        </script> Not sure if you can add values like in script tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working - had to authorize app. I missed that part.